# Evaluate the piecewise defined function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

### Evaluate the piecewise defined function at the indicated values.

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
3  & \text{x≤5} \\
5x-6, & \text{if x>5}
\end{cases}$

$f(−6) = -6$

$f(0)  = 0 $f(5)  = 5

$f(6)  = 24 $

$f(8)  = 34 $

Are my answers correct?

Thank you

Comment: You can easily check this in an online calculator.

Comment: I honestly don't know which one I would use. Could you provide a link, excuse my n00bism.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: To evaluate this function for a given value of $x$, (1) find which condition on the right side that $x$ satisfies, then (2) use the rule to the left of the condition to find the value of $f(x)$. So, suppose we want to find $f(-6)$ as you ask. You must ask yourself "If $x$ is $-6$, which of the conditions is satisfied?" The conditions are "$x\leq 5$" and "$x>5$". So you are asking which of "$-6\leq 5$" and "$-6>5$" is true. Obviously the first is true and the second is not (only one will be true). Then use the corresponding rule: $f(-6)=3$. The rule will always be $f(x)=3$ or $f(x)=5x-6$.

Comment: So, with that in mind since of course f(0) is "x≤5" would also be 3? as f(-6) is.

Answer (score 1):

The three first are wrong :

$f(-6)=f(0)=f(5)=3$ because $-6\leq0\leq5$

The two last one are correct :

$f(6)=5\times6-6=24$ because $6\geq5$

$f(8)=5\times8-6=34$ because $8\geq5$

Answer (score 0):

The last two are correct. You are doing something very wrong for the first three, but I don't know what because you have given no working.

You need to pay close attention to the ranges to which each piece of the function applies.